# How to carry a gun across federal lands

Tags: firearms, new-hampshire, open-carry

In America, the federal court generally rules that the second amendment of the constitution is implied to be more restrictive than liberating, so carrying a firearm on federal property is often illegal in states where there are relatively few restrictions on the right to bear arms, like in NH. The laws on firearm use, carry, and ownership are notoriously byzantine.

I'm wondering how NH citizens who legally can carry as per NH law could legally and openly carry a firearm despite federal restrictions? Some locals want to pick up trash here in NH and openly carry pistols to normalize (make acceptable) bearing firearms. Is it sometimes legal to carry if there is a federal building along the way? The goal is to walk along the easement. Is it ever/always/never legal to use the easement of federal land along a NH road while openly carrying a pistol despite not being active duty military/police? If the easement is irrelevant, the same question applies.

Comment: "Easement" seems like an odd word to use. If the building is used by the federal government, wouldn't the underlying land either be owned (fee simple) by the federal government, or by a landlord?

Comment: Federal land vs federal building might be a big distinction.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite, this question regard land that and not the federal building per se. Currently, I'm under the impression that I may legally carry a firearm on the sidewalk of the post office, but not on the parking lot, so I *expect* and hope similar standards to apply to easements on federally managed land here in NH as well.

Comment: "Federally managed land" is a wide net to cast.  The White Mountain National Forest, for example, doesn't seem to have any special rules governing firearms beyond state law.  As for post offices, the federal regulation that prohibits firearms, [39 CFR 232.1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/39/232.1) does purport to prohibit them on public sidewalks that fall within the property line of the post office.  I don't know how that plays out in New Hampshire.

Comment: Note that for many (if not all) Federal facilities, there must be clearly posted signs that firearms are not allowed, and you cannot be convicted of carrying a firearm in such facilities if such signs are not conspicuous and you not given "actual notice" of these regulations. [See 18 USC § 930(h).](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/930)

Comment: This and your other question used the word "easement" in a very unusual way.  Are you familiar with [the usual definition](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/easements-overview.html)?  It typically means something like one person having the right to cross a neighbor's land to access their own, or a utility company having the right to run pipes or cables through someone's property.  So I think it would help if you explain your intended meaning more carefully, instead of assuming that people will automatically understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Federal rules concerning carrying firearms generally apply only to federal buildings, military bases and Indian reservations. National Forests, BLM lands and National Parks are governed by state law. The [Concealed Carry web site](https://www.usconcealedcarry.com/resources/federal-ccw-law/federally-banned-locations-for-carrying-firearms/) contains more detailed information summarizing the legal situation.

Comment: It looks like the sidewalk is fair game for the post office: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/39/232.1

Comment: @haleonj Usually sidewalks are on town property, not private property. Things like the immediate grounds and parking lot of a building are considered to be in the "environs" of the building and can be construed to be part of the building proper.